# Where does deja-dup log its errors?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I configured Deja-dup to make a daily backup of my whole data drive. Now I get an error message each time, telling me, that not all files could be backuped. But i cannot find any Deja-dup logs in `/var/log` nor in the syslog. Where does it display the missing files?

Comment: Did you check /tmp/deja-dup.log?

Comment: I could not find a file there

Answer (score 13):

It seems that it doesn't really save them anywhere, but if you run it with the environment variable `DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1` you can get all the information that way.

Source: https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/125731

Comment: Now that is some verbose output. The log file has >500MB for one run of deja dup. My solution is now to run the command manually again and check the gui output.

Comment: `DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup` seems to work to get output to console (it should be possible to redirect it wherever desired), thank You, but I think it's worth mentioning, that the application should de closed before running it. `killall deja-dup` should help (maybe also `killall deja-dup-monitor` could be required).

Answer (score 4):

In Deja-Dup on Ubuntu 16.04 (default Backup app installation), there are limited log files in `~/.cache/deja-dup/`. It looks like only fairly basic information is stored by default.