# Reading full deja-dup progress log

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

While restoring backed-up data, the attending window shows the last 100 actions in the Details box. Especially for lengthy operations, I would be interested in perusing the full list and seeing what Deja-dup has actually done in the meantime

Is this list being saved somewhere that you know?

For the next time, can this be achieved by launching the backup from the command line, which could then be a better option?

This other post deals with standard error that might be produced:
[Where does deja-dup log its errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190446/where-does-deja-dup-log-its-errors)
while I am interested in the standard output which is actually produced.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with deja-dup, but I would suggest just launching a terminal and redirecting std out into whatever log you want

Comment: @j-money I suspect that too, but deja-dup is a front-end for duplicity operating in the back-end. Although there are man pages for both, I hope that someone comes with proven answers since I hesitate to make experiments with backed-up data. Thanks for the tip anyhow